# Blazor how to acces Configuration from non-UI class

Tags: blazor, app-config

I need to read some settings out of App.Config in a blazor server app (.Net 5).  My class is running on a background thread and is not part of a component.

Is there a way to access the Configuration object that is created in the Startup class (or instantiate a new instance)?

For example,  var x = Configuration.GetConnectionString('conStr').

All of the examples I have found assume a component is being used.

Comment: Are your (class)service implemented as a backgroundservice and registered in the DI container with AddHostedService?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, .Net 5 use .Net core configuration.
Read [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for details.
Blazor use the same mechanism, and Blazor WASM apps load there configuration from an *appsettings.json*. The doc is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Hi, just looking through the documentation linked to, all of the examples provided require being passed in a 'service' or a 'Host' variable to the appropriate code.  In a background thread I do not have access to these items.